# Universe, controverse, controversy, universy

Tags: etymology

Why isn’t it "a controverse"? Or why isn’t it a "universy"?

Etymonline implies that the "verse" part of [controversy](https://www.etymonline.com/word/controversy#etymonline_v_18300) and [universe](https://www.etymonline.com/word/universe#etymonline_v_4519) come from the same Latin root: versus, past participle of vertere.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/controverse) says "controverse" is obsolete and has been since before 1800 (Google books start).

Is there any reason that controversy gets a "y" but universe doesn’t?

Comment: They usually go -erse, -ersity or -ersion. I'm not sure if this is the reason for asking the question, but "controversy" is the only -vert word that has a -ersy form). I thought it was a silly question before I realised that "controversy" is unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary (OED) says "universe" comes from Latin *ūniversum*—a past participle form. It has no Y or I after the S. It seems pretty clear that this is the reason why we don't have **universy.*

In contrast, *controversy* comes from Latin *contrōversia;* the Y in the English word comes from the I in the Latin word.

*Controverse* does exist as an alternative form/word; the OED entry for *controversy* says "Compare later controverse n." and "In French the usual word is now controverse (1285 in Old French)." In French, the Latin ending *-ia* often corresponds to *-e;* for example, the endings *-ance/-ence* come from Latin *-antia/-entia.* But it sometimes could correspond to *-ie* instead, as in *[modestie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/modestie).*